# List of dictionaries vs nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

To explain a little my environment, I need to keep track of users and a collection of things each user own. This is highly dynamic, although the number of base users is always higher than the collection of things they own. I decided to go with something like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, MyClass>> ActiveUsers = 
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, MyClass>>();
```

In this case, the `TKey` for the parent Dictionary is the connectionId of an user, and the `TKey` for the inner dictionary is a string that represents the Id of `MyClass`
What I meant before is that ActiveUsers will hold (hopefully) a  great number of TKeys, while the TValues will normally hold less than 10 items. As these items are related, when a user disconnects, it is deleted from the parent Dictionary, and all other items in the parent Dictionary will be searched for some value in their inner dictionary and these will be deleted if present.
This field will be accessed constantly (extremely often) and I'm trying to achieve the best performance possible.

Is this a better approach (performance-related) than creating a class with an ID and `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` as fields and holding a list of this class?
Would something like this be better?

```
public class ActiveUsersManager
{
    public string Id{ get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, MyClass> ActiveUsers { get; private set; }

    public ActiveUsersManager(string connectionId)
    {
        Id = connectionId;
        ActiveUsers = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
    }
}

//In another class
private static List<ActiveUsersManager> ActiveUsers = new List<ActiveUsersManager>();
```

If it helps, the ActiveUsers is a static field in an ASP.NET Controller.

EDIT: answering comments

This dictionary is consumed as this:

```
public static MyClass GetInformation(string myId, string objectId)
{
    //Validation removed
    Dictionary<string, MyClass> dictionaryResult = null;
    MyClass result = null;

    if (!ActiveUsers.TryGetValue(myId, out dictionaryResult)) //check if the user was already added to the Dictionary
    {
        dictionaryResult = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
        result = new MyClass(objectId);
        dictionaryResult.Add(objectId, result);
        ActiveUsers.Add(myId, dictionaryResult);
    }
    else if (!dictionaryResult.TryGetValue(objectId, out result)) //otherwise check if the user already has this item
    {
        result = new MyClass(objectId);
        dictionaryResult.Add(objectId, result);
        ActiveUsers.Add(myId, dictionaryResult);
    }
    //else everything is already set-up
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: Code that shows how the inner items are deleted

```
public static void RemoveUserAndSessions(string userId, string objectId)
{ 
    ActiveUsers.Remove(userId);
    foreach (Dictionary<string, MyClass> dic in ActiveUsers.Values)
        dic.Remove(objectId);
}
```

This is the first ASP.NET application I work in, and I haven't done any multithreading that involved dictionaries before, how could I make this thread-safe?

EDIT: trying to make things more clear.

I didn't want to reveal details, but I guess they are needed to understand the reason behind this. This is for a chat application. Each user is stored in ActiveUsers to keep track of, well, active users. Each user has a Dictionary of the clients they are connected with, and the MyClass object contains a set of properties needed for the client to communicate. As soon as a user disconnects, all the active sessions must be immediately deleted, hence the delete method. I imagine this could be done by creating another class to hold active sessions in a Dictionary and have this class in the original Dictionary.
As suggested, I'll take a look at the ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: Made a Console application to test this... While the nested dictionary takes 0.15 seconds to go through 50.000 base items and 10 inner items, the list takes 57.34 seconds to go through the same collection...

Comment: Why do you want to use Dictionaries, exactly?  You almost certainly do not need to use nested Dictionaries and should just design a class or interface, instead.  Using Dictionaries, especially nested, will make your code much more complicated and harder to debug/maintain.

Comment: @R.Salisbury because of the O(1) to look for a specific object in the collection? The method that is mostly used takes less than 15 lines using the nested dictionary. What other implementation would you suggest to do this?

Comment: You're right about that, but you still should really not use a Dictionary of Dictionaries.  Use a dictionary of ActiveUsers or ActiveUserLookups, and if you really need another Dictionary, make it a property of the class you assign to the parent Dictionary's Value, rather than the Value of the Dictionary itself.  It just makes the code much easier to read/maintain.

Comment: How exactly are you consuming this dictionary? Also, you're using a `static` dictionary in a multi-threaded environment, where dictionary isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov see my edit

Comment: `ActiveUsers` is not thread safe, you could be corrupting state due to the `ActiveUsers.Add` call you have ouside of any kind of lock in the static method. You also can't read from `ActiveUsers` while someone is writing to it, it is only safe to have multiple readers and no writers or no readers and one writer.

Comment: The usage you posted seems ok (ignoring the thread safety). But what concerns me is the following part of your explanation `As these items are related, when a user disconnects, it is deleted from the parent Dictionary, and all other items in the parent Dictionary will be searched for some value in their inner dictionary and these will be deleted if present.` Could you post that code too?

Comment: @IvanStoev see my edit

Comment: @ScottChamberlain see my edit

Comment: Are you trying to prevent multiple logins by the same user?

Comment: The new function just makes it worse. Switch over to a `ConcurrentDictionary` or go do some research on how to do proper locking

Comment: If the items your users have are shared, why does each user have their own instance of each?  
  

I also really think you should rename that list.  You have a list of ActiveUserManagers (and to me, Manager indicates a singleton) called ActiveUsers, each of which has a property called ActiveUsers.

Comment: @R.Salisbury and everyone else, see my edit

Comment: From what you have shown, using list instead of dictionary for the root information would be much worse than what you have currently. The current bottleneck is your `RemoveUserAndSessions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly advise structuring the data more like this:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ActiveUser> ActiveUsers { get; set; }

private class ActiveUser {
   public int ConnectionId { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
}   
// . . . 
Dictionary<string, ActiveUser> ActiveUsers = new Dictionary<string, ActiveUser>();
```

(Note: If you are using C# < 6, just initialize the dictionary in the `ActiveUser` constructor)

And for your delete method, you may want to do something such as:

```
public static void RemoveUserAndSessions(string userId, string objectId)
{ 
    ActiveUsers.Remove(userId);
    Parallel.ForEach(ActiveUsers.Values, dic => dic.Remove(objectId));
}
```

Edit: Renamed some things for clarity.

Comment: I did something very similar to this, but instead of using a Dictionary in your MyClasses, I also used a ConcurrentDictionary. And I forgot about Parallel.ForEach, thanks for reminding about it!
Edit: BTW, ConcurrentDictionary doesn't have a Remove method, but rather TryRemove

Answer (score 0):

The main problem from performance perspective I see in your design is the need to iterate all the dictionaries during the `RemoveUserAndSessions` method. Here is a sample design that does not have that problem

```
static class UserManager
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, User> ActiveUsers = new Dictionary<string, User>();
    public static User GetInformation(string userId)
    {
        lock (ActiveUsers)
        {
            User user;
            if (!ActiveUsers.TryGetValue(userId, out user))
                ActiveUsers.Add(userId, user = new User(userId));
            return user;
        }
    }
    public static void RemoveUserAndSessions(string userId)
    {
        lock (ActiveUsers)
        {
            User user;
            if (ActiveUsers.TryGetValue(userId, out user))
            {
                ActiveUsers.Remove(userId);
                user.EndAllSessions();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void StartSession(string firstUserId, string secondUserId)
    {
        lock (ActiveUsers)
        {
            var firstUser = GetInformation(firstUserId);
            var secondUser = GetInformation(secondUserId);
            firstUser.StartSession(secondUser);
            secondUser.StartSession(firstUser);
        }
    }
}
class User
{
    private Dictionary<string, User> sessions = new Dictionary<string, User>();
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public User(string id) { Id = id; }
    public void StartSession(User other)
    {
        sessions.Add(other.Id, other);
    }
    public void EndSession(User other)
    {
        sessions.Remove(other.Id);
    }
    public void EndAllSessions()
    {
        foreach (var other in sessions.Values)
            other.EndSession(this);
        sessions.Clear();
    }
}
```

This is just to get the idea, hope you can map it to your concrete case.